# Create docker image to run selenium tests on different browser versions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am currently learning to use docker to run selenium tests.
However, to run tests on different versions of the browser, it requires creating our own image.

I tried few ways but failed to run them.
I used the docker file at below path:

https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/~/dockerfile/

and tried to build the image by using the following command:

> docker build -t my-chrome-image --build-arg CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=2.23 --build-arg CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-beta=53.0.2785.92-1 NodeChrome

Can anyone guide me on how to implement the same?

Regards,

Ashwin Karangutkar

Comment: Instead of creating different images, you could start existing docker images from different releases that have internally different browser versions. As an example, start a Selenium Grid from `2.53.1-beryllium` in port `4444`  and start another Selenium Grid from `3.0.1-aluminum` in port `5555`. You just have to check if their versions are suitable for you.

Comment: @Tom  3.0.0 picks the latest, so we need to build your own image with specific version. See this : [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/17)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
docker build -t my-chrome-image --build-arg CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=2.23 --build-arg CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-beta <path_to_Dockerfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using elgalu/selenium.

```
docker run -d --name=grid -p 4444:24444 -p 5900:25900 --shm-size=1g elgalu/selenium
```

And looking in [elgalu](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium) looks like you can change the browser versions.
Adding **-e FIREFOX_VERSION=38.0.6** to the docker run command.